# Space of equivalence classes of sets is complete

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X, F, P)$ be a measurable space. Define an equivalence relation ~ on F by A ~ B if and only if $P(A \Delta B) = 0$, and let $F^*$ be the space of equivalence classes. Then this space is complete under the metric $d(A,B)=P(A \Delta B)$.

It's pretty easy to show that everything is well defined and that $d$ actually defines a metric, however, I'm not sure exactly how to show the space is complete. If $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then we can inductively pull out a subsequence with $\Sigma P(x_{n_i}) < \infty$, and apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that $P(lim sup \; x_{n_i}) = 0.$ But I'm not sure if this is useful. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Because $d(A,D)=\|1_A-1_B\|_1$, you should be able to extract the completeness of $(F^*,d)$ from the completeness of $L^1$. Is the latter something you have at your disposal?

Comment: It isn't unforunately

Comment: Does your claim $P(limsup x_{n_i})=0$ make sense for the cauchy sequence consisting of the same event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's adjust your approach. Let $\{A_n\}$ be $d$-Cauchy. Pull out a subsequence $\{A_{n_k}\}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty d(A_{n_{k+1}},A_{n_k})<\infty$. Now Borel-Cantelli it to conclude that $P[\limsup_k (A_{n_{k+1}}\Delta A_{n_k})]=0$. This means that for $P$-a.e. $x\in X$, the sequence $\{1_{A_{n_k}}(x)\}$ is either eventually all $1$s or eventually all $0$s. Define $A:=\liminf_k A_{n_k}$ (which is just those $x$s for which $\{1_{A_{n_k}}(x)\}$ is  eventually all $1$s) and show that $d(A,A_{n_k})\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. The Cauchy property lets you extend this convergence to the entire sequence.